# How do you summarize columns based on unique IDs without knowing IDs in R?

Tags: r, count, plyr, dplyr, summary

I've been going through the posts regarding summarizing data, but haven't seem to have found what I'm looking for.

I wish to create a summary "count-table" which will allow me to see how often a certain medication was given to patients. The fact that some patients received multiple medications simultaneously doesn't matter, because I simply want a summary of all the medication given and then calculate which percentage each medication class is of all medication given. The issue is, that I don't know the names of the possible medication given, they're "hidden" somewhere in the `data.frame`, thus, I have to specify which columns R would have to look through first to create a "list" by which it can then summarize the columns.

I anticipate that this points towards the `plyr` package but my attempts to use the functions in it correctly haven't worked until now.

My `df` looks something like this

```
x <- sample(letters[1:4], 20, replace = TRUE)
y <- sample(letters[1:5], 20, replace = TRUE)
z <- sample(letters[1:6], 20, replace = TRUE)
df<-data.frame(x,y,z)
head(df)
  x y z
1 a a f
2 a c d
3 b b e
4 c d b
5 a a b
6 c d d
```

as you can see, the `data.frame` contains three columns which have the same but also different letters, indicating the name of the medication given.

What I'd now like to do is create a list of unique characters,

```
unique(x)
unique(y)
unique(z)
```

which serves as my reference list by which R can then summarize the counts in each column.

```
summary(df)
```

returns a summary of counts of each column but not of each ID itself and also without a percentage of all unique counts.

I also tried the following, which sort of goes in the right direction, but ideally, I'd like to have a list of unique characters, which I can feed to the `length` argument

```
ddply(df, .(x), summarize, counts=length(unique(y)))
```

Any idea how I could do this? Help much appreciated.

Comment: sapply(df , function(x) names(table(x)) )

Comment: @BondedDust I'd use `lapply` instead of `sapply`. If every `names(table(x))` happen to return a vector of same length, the output will be an array instead of a list and this may cause problems if you need to subsequently handle that object.

Comment: Right. Could even use `lapply(df, function(x) list( nams=unique(x), count=length(unique(x)))`

Comment: Thanks guys, but I don't think this is the solution to my question. This returns the number of levels of each character per column, but doesn't give me the total sum counts in the whole df. For example the letter `a` occurs 16 times in the df...and this is what I would like to have as the output. Type `summary(df)` and you'll see the summary count of each character per column, but I want it of the whole df and then also to return the percentage of total counts each character has. That's why I though the `ddply` function may be more adequate than `lapply()`...thanks for your time and help!

Comment: I think I found a solution and i'm quite curious what you think of my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to have a count for the whole dataframe, you can use `table(unlist(df))` (see also @goctlr's answer) & if you also want to have probabilities: `prop.table(table(unlist(df)))`. When you also want to get the count for the individual columns, it gets more difficult.

To get the count for each column and the total count, I wrote the following function:

```
# some reproducible data:
set.seed(1)
x <- sample(letters[1:4], 20, replace = TRUE)
y <- sample(letters[1:5], 20, replace = TRUE)
z <- sample(letters[1:6], 20, replace = TRUE)
df <- data.frame(x,y,z)

# the function
func <- function(x) {
  x2 <- data.frame()
  nms <- names(x)
  id <- sort(unique(unlist(x)))
  for(i in 1:length(id)) {
    for(j in 1:length(nms)) {
      x2[i,j] <- sum(x[,j] %in% id[i])
    }
  }
  names(x2) <- nms
  x2$total <- rowSums(x2)
  x2 <- cbind(id,x2)
  assign("dat", x2, envir = .GlobalEnv)
}
```

Executing the function with `func(df)` will give you a dataframe `dat` in your global envirenment:

```
> dat
  id x y z total
1  a 4 4 3    11
2  b 5 5 2    12
3  c 5 4 4    13
4  d 6 4 5    15
5  e 0 3 5     8
6  f 0 0 1     1
```

After that, you can calculate the percentages with for example the `dplyr` package:

```
library(dplyr)
dat <- dat %>% mutate(xperc=round(100*x/sum(total),1),
                      yperc=round(100*y/sum(total),1),
                      zperc=round(100*z/sum(total),1),
                      perc=round(100*total/sum(total),1))
```

which results in:

```
> dat
  id x y z total xperc yperc zperc perc
1  a 4 4 3    11   6.7   6.7   5.0 18.3
2  b 5 5 2    12   8.3   8.3   3.3 20.0
3  c 5 4 4    13   8.3   6.7   6.7 21.7
4  d 6 4 5    15  10.0   6.7   8.3 25.0
5  e 0 3 5     8   0.0   5.0   8.3 13.3
6  f 0 0 1     1   0.0   0.0   1.7  1.7
```

Comment: Jaap, this is an excellent function! I will actually be using this quite a lot, as its a great way to summarize factors quickly to get an overview of what's happening in a df! However, I have a small problem. When applying the second part of your reply, I get the error message `Error: could not find function "%>%"`. Any ideas why? Further, is there anyway, one could actually append a column to the `dat` df which then shows the percentage of the total? Or should I just save the mutated `dat` as `dat2` and then `data.frame(dat, dat2)`? Thanks for a great answer!

Comment: Ahhh, stupid me. I typed `library(plyr)` and not `dplyr`! My fault. Sorry!!! 
I have a further small question, because perhaps I wasn't clear. Ideally, I'd like to have the percentage of variable `a` of the sum of the `total` column. I re-wrote the mutate to `dat2 <- dat %>% mutate(Percentage=100*total/sum(total)`- is that right? It looks ok...Thanks for your time and help!

Comment: @OFish That's correct. (by the way: you forgot a `)` at the end of your code in your last comment)

Comment: I do have to say @Jaap - this is such a handy little piece of code, I think I'll attempt to try and extend it a bit further, so that I can build `data.tables` like dat and perform things like `chisq.tests` across the rows etc. with the `p-values` as an appended column. Not that it's the best way of analyzing data, but it's just such a fast way of making tables for papers etc...I'm really, really excited about this. Thank you again.

Answer (score 1):

For a summary of counts for the whole data frame you can unlist the data frame and then call the table function:

```
table(unlist(df))
```

To get the percentage of total counts, save the result and use the prop.table function:

```
tout <- table(unlist(df))
prop.table(tout)
```

Comment: Thanks @goctlr that's a handy little function to have. Personally, I find Jaap's answer provides a format, that's the nicest, but it's a good thing to have that `prop.table` function. Thanks for your time and help!

Comment: Nice and simple answer. How I understood the question however, was that @OFish also wanted the counts for the individual columns. That's why I didn't give this answer. I also included the `table` & `prop.table` functions in my answer now to make it more complete.