# How do you run a chisq.test on two different dplyr outputs and then summarize it in a table?

Tags: r, function, dplyr

The question I have is related to one I posted a while back [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26294297/how-do-you-summarize-columns-based-on-unique-ids-without-knowing-ids-in-r/26346991#26346991)

Jaap was fantastic, in that he's helped me create this wonderful output of summary tables of counts and frequencies (percentage) of categorical variables.

The "real data" that I'm analysing is from two different hospitals, each with a different frequency of drugs given and *but* not always were the same drugs given.

The summary from Jaap's `func` function from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26294297/how-do-you-summarize-columns-based-on-unique-ids-without-knowing-ids-in-r/26346991#26346991) looks as follows, and the whole `data.frame` is provided below (hospitals number one and two):

```
                      id AB1 AB2 AB3 AB4 AB5 AB6 AB7 AB8 AB9 AB10 AB11 AB12 AB13 total perc
1  1st gen Cephalosporin   4   0   0   1   1   0   0   0   0    0    0    0    0     6  1.9
2  3rd gen Cephalosporin  44   7   8   1   3   2   0   0   0    0    0    0    0    65 20.5
3  4th gen Cephalosporin   3   3   0   1   2   1   0   0   0    0    0    0    0    10  3.2
```

Now I'd like to run a `chisq.test` (or `Fisher's` if frequency lower 5) of all the variable (names) found in the `id` column using the total frequency found in the `total` column by comparing hospital one versus hospital two.

So in layman terms I want to answer the following question: "Were 1st gen Cephalosporins given more frequently in hospital one compared to hospital two?" etc.

As some variable id's may not be identical between hospitals, I anticipate, this may return a `NULL` calculation.

Ideally, I'd then like to summarize all of these findings in a table with the correpsonding p-value to look as follows:

```
id    Hospital One Total Frequency      Hospital Two Total Frequency   p-value
xyz   15                                30                             0.01
```

Thank you very much for your help.

All the data can be found below.

Cheers

**EDIT following Khashaa's issues raised:**

***This is simply a mock-output (ideally, what I would like to have).***

```
id    Hospital One Total Frequency      Hospital Two Total Frequency   p-value
xyz   n                                 i                              x.xx
```

As mentioned, the p-value should be derived from a `chisq.test` or `fisher.test`.

I gather the output will have to be generated somehow this way, with Hospital #1 called `hosp1` and Hospital #2 called `hosp2`

```
# first take those columns of the dplyr output your interested in
hosp1_sel<-hosp1[,c("id","total")]
hosp2_sel<-hosp2[,c("id","total")]
#then merge the data.frames to one so you can perform analysis on one dataframe
new_df <- merge(hosp1_sel, hosp2_sel, by=0)
#this looks like this
> new_df
   Row.names                  id.x total.x                  id.y total.y
1          1 1st gen Cephalosporin       6 3rd gen Cephalosporin      19
2         10          Trimethoprim       2           Polypeptide       1
3         11      Ureidopenicillin      46             Rifamycin       1
4         12            Carbapenem      19          Tetracycline       1
5         13        Fluorquinolone      17           Lincosamide       1
6         14         Nitromidazole      12             Quinolone       2
7         15            Antifungal       6          Sulfonamides       2
8         16         Oxazolidinone       2        Nitroimidazole       1
9         17             Rifamycin       1            Polymyxine       1
10        18           Polypeptide       1              Colistin       1
11         2 3rd gen Cephalosporin      65            Carbapenem      37
12         3 4th gen Cephalosporin      10       Fluoroquinolone      24
13         4        Aminoglycoside      31          Glycopeptide      32
14         5           Clindamycin       2            Penicillin      29
15         6          Glycopeptide      55      Ureidopenicillin      36
16         7             Macrolide       3           Lipopeptide       4
17         8            Penicillin      36              Macrolid       2
18         9          Tetracycline       2        Aminoglycoside       9
```

This is where I get stuck. 
In my mind I'd now have to make this `data.frame` wider, to then be able to run something like:

```
chisq.test(hosp1$Ureidopenicillin, hosp2$Ureidopenicillin)
```

To determine, if "Ureidopenicillins" were given more frequently in hospital #1 compared to hospital #2 and so forth.

The issue is, that this actually is comparing "counts" and not "proportions" from a contingency table though...

Any ideas?

O.

Hospital #1 `data.frame`:

```
structure(list(id = structure(1:19, .Label = c("1st gen Cephalosporin", 
"3rd gen Cephalosporin", "4th gen Cephalosporin", "Aminoglycoside", 
"Clindamycin", "Glycopeptide", "Macrolide", "Penicillin", "Tetracycline", 
"Trimethoprim", "Ureidopenicillin", "Carbapenem", "Fluorquinolone", 
"Nitromidazole", "Antifungal", "Oxazolidinone", "Rifamycin", 
"Polypeptide", "Lipopeptide "), class = "factor"), AB1 = c(4L, 
44L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 7L, 1L, 7L, 2L, 1L, 12L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L), AB2 = c(0L, 7L, 3L, 7L, 0L, 16L, 2L, 9L, 0L, 0L, 
9L, 1L, 2L, 6L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), AB3 = c(0L, 8L, 0L, 5L, 
1L, 13L, 0L, 5L, 0L, 0L, 12L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), 
    AB4 = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 6L, 0L, 5L, 0L, 8L, 0L, 0L, 5L, 3L, 4L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L), AB5 = c(1L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 0L, 4L, 
    0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), AB6 = c(0L, 
    2L, 1L, 3L, 0L, 5L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L), AB7 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 3L, 0L, 
    0L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L), AB8 = c(0L, 0L, 
    0L, 3L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 1L), AB9 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 2L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), AB10 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 
    1L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L), AB11 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), AB12 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L
    ), AB13 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), total = c(6, 65, 10, 31, 2, 
    55, 3, 36, 2, 2, 46, 19, 17, 12, 6, 2, 1, 1, 1), perc = c(1.9, 
    20.5, 3.2, 9.8, 0.6, 17.4, 0.9, 11.4, 0.6, 0.6, 14.5, 6, 
    5.4, 3.8, 1.9, 0.6, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3)), class = "data.frame", .Names = c("id", 
"AB1", "AB2", "AB3", "AB4", "AB5", "AB6", "AB7", "AB8", "AB9", 
"AB10", "AB11", "AB12", "AB13", "total", "perc"), row.names = c(NA, 
-19L))
```

Hospital #2 `data.frame`:

```
structure(list(id = structure(1:18, .Label = c("3rd gen Cephalosporin", 
"Carbapenem", "Fluoroquinolone", "Glycopeptide", "Penicillin", 
"Ureidopenicillin", "Lipopeptide", "Macrolid", "Aminoglycoside", 
"Polypeptide", "Rifamycin", "Tetracycline", "Lincosamide", "Quinolone", 
"Sulfonamides", "Nitroimidazole", "Polymyxine", "Colistin"), class = "factor"), 
    AB1 = c(9L, 3L, 1L, 7L, 16L, 22L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), AB2 = c(2L, 17L, 5L, 8L, 2L, 9L, 
    1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), AB3 = c(1L, 
    9L, 4L, 5L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L), AB4 = c(1L, 3L, 3L, 7L, 4L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), AB5 = c(3L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 
    4L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L), 
    AB6 = c(3L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L), AB7 = c(0L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L), total = c(19, 
    37, 24, 32, 29, 36, 4, 2, 9, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1), 
    perc = c(9.4, 18.2, 11.8, 15.8, 14.3, 17.7, 2, 1, 4.4, 0.5, 
    0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 1, 1, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5)), class = "data.frame", .Names = c("id", 
"AB1", "AB2", "AB3", "AB4", "AB5", "AB6", "AB7", "total", "perc"
), row.names = c(NA, -18L))
```

Comment: Mind providing a minimal worked example? For instance, how did you calculate `p-value=0.01` on your desired output format?

Comment: @khashaa - that output example is made up and simply illustrates how the final result should look like.

Comment: Unless you show just one instance of the calculation of the p-values, using your actual datasets, I have no idea where you would pull out such numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Merging by `hospital <- left_join(hosp1, hosp2, by = "id") %>% select(id, total.x, total.y)` resulted in

```
                     #id total.x total.y
#1  1st gen Cephalosporin       6      NA
#2  3rd gen Cephalosporin      65      19
#3  4th gen Cephalosporin      10      NA
#4         Aminoglycoside      31       9
#5            Clindamycin       2      NA
#6           Glycopeptide      55      32
#7              Macrolide       3      NA
#8             Penicillin      36      29
#9           Tetracycline       2       1
#10          Trimethoprim       2      NA
#11      Ureidopenicillin      46      36
#12            Carbapenem      19      37
#13        Fluorquinolone      17      NA
#14         Nitromidazole      12      NA
#15            Antifungal       6      NA
#16         Oxazolidinone       2      NA
#17             Rifamycin       1       1
#18           Polypeptide       1       1
#19          Lipopeptide        1      NA
```

Strange that too many `NA`s produced for `hosp2`. Upon closer inspection, there are inconsistencies among `id` variables. For instance, 14th row in `hosp1` is `Nitromidazole` whereas 16th row in `hosp2` is `Nitroimidazole`, and I am not sure if they are indicating the same medication.

Anyway, though I have some doubts about your use of `chisq.test`, the desired output can be produced as follows

```
pval <- function(x, y){ 
  ifelse(!is.na(x) & !is.na(y), chisq.test(c(x, y))$p.value, NA)
  }
p <- lapply(1:length(hospital$total.x), 
        function(i){
          pval(hospital$total.x[i],hospital$total.y[i]) 
                 }
           )
hospital$p_value <- unlist(p)
colnames(hospital) <- c("id", "Hospital One Total Frequency", "Hospital Two Total Frequency", "p-value")
```

Final output looks

```
> hospital
#                      id Hospital One Total Frequency Hospital Two Total Frequency      p-value
#1  1st gen Cephalosporin                            6                           NA           NA
#2  3rd gen Cephalosporin                           65                           19 5.193805e-07
#3  4th gen Cephalosporin                           10                           NA           NA
#4         Aminoglycoside                           31                            9 5.042182e-04
#5            Clindamycin                            2                           NA           NA
#6           Glycopeptide                           55                           32 1.366852e-02
#7              Macrolide                            3                           NA           NA
#8             Penicillin                           36                           29 3.852612e-01
#9           Tetracycline                            2                            1 5.637029e-01
#10          Trimethoprim                            2                           NA           NA
#11      Ureidopenicillin                           46                           36 2.694564e-01
#12            Carbapenem                           19                           37 1.615693e-02
#13        Fluorquinolone                           17                           NA           NA
#14         Nitromidazole                           12                           NA           NA
#15            Antifungal                            6                           NA           NA
#16         Oxazolidinone                            2                           NA           NA
#17             Rifamycin                            1                            1 1.000000e+00
#18           Polypeptide                            1                            1 1.000000e+00
#19          Lipopeptide                             1                           NA           NA
```

Comment: Thank you Khashaa. I didn't know of the `left_join` function, which is simply fantastic! Will correct the misspelling etc. The `data.frames` I received are soooo messy, I've spent days cleaning them. 
The function you wrote is awesome too. I understand your concerns about the `chisq.test`- my opinion is that it's suboptimal because were effectively comparing counts and not proportions. If counts are being compared, one could theoretically change the function to include the `wilcox.test`. Would you agree or are your concerns different? I have marked this as an answer however and upvoted. Thx.

Comment: Thank you. Yes, I used that youtube video to learn how to use dplyr - is it yours? I'll have a look at Hadley's tutorial too. Your thoughts on the `chisq.test`?

Comment: No, that is not my video. On the usage of the tests: Firstly,  I doubt they are altogether necessary. After all, you can tell "whether a particular drug is given more frequently at 1 than 2" just by looking at the data, without resort to any testing. Secondly, when applied to a vector, as in your case, `chisq.test` is a two-sided test, but "whether Ureidopenicillins were given more frequently in hospital #1 compared to hospital #2" is one-sided hypothesis. Anyway, I feel that the issues regarding the use of tests are best left to you.

Comment: Thanks Khashaa, thanks for clarifying your thoughts. Yes, I totally agree that the data says it all. But I gather you know clinicians and how "fixed on p-values" they are. The way the question is formulated is of course one-sided, but the comparison is effectively two-sided, as I'm not pre-determining that one or the other gave more or less. But thank you for sharing your thoughts. I totally agree, this is my / the investigators call. Was simply intrigued to hear your answer. Cheers,

Comment: the left_join function seems to remove those names in the `id` column of `hosp2` that aren't in `hosp1`...any idea why that happens? I've gone through `inner_join()`, `semi_join()` etc and the help file, but it only says, that it'll take the column from x and match y...but how can one do both? Cheers.

Comment: I thought that'd be all right because the result is NA for NA observations. If your want to retain all of the `id`s in combined data, use `merge(hosp1, hosp2, by = "id", all=TRUE)`. It is almost self-evident that `left_join` keeps the `id` for a data on the "left" - equivalent to `merge(., x=TRUE, y=FALSE)`- you can try `left_join(hosp2, hosp1, by = "id")`. For large datasets, dplyr's join operators are much faster than `merge`, though unfortunately I couldn't find `merge(., all=TRUE)` equivalent.

Comment: Thanks. That's why I checked the other `_join` functions. Thanks for your input and thoughts. Really helpful! Cheers, O.