# How do summarize this data table with dplyr, then run a chisq.test (or similar) on the results and loop it all into one neat function?

Tags: r, function, dplyr, chi-squared

This question was embedded in another question I asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28979696/can-someone-tell-me-why-r-is-not-using-the-whole-data-frame-for-this-chisq-test?noredirect=1#comment46210803_28979696), but as it goes beyond the scope of what I wanted to know in the initial inquiry, I thought it might deserve a separate thread.

I've been trying to come up with a solution for this problem based on the answers I have received [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26294297/how-do-you-summarize-columns-based-on-unique-ids-without-knowing-ids-in-r/26366300?noredirect=1#comment41420996_26366300) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27394623/how-do-you-run-a-chisq-test-on-two-different-dplyr-outputs-and-then-summarize-it/27414121?noredirect=1#comment43344092_27414121) using `dplyr` and the functions written by [Khashaa](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3573401/khashaa) and [Jaap](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2204410/jaap).

Using the solutions provided to me (especially from Jaap), I have been able to summarize the raw data I received into a matrix-looking data table

```
dput(SO_Example_v1)
structure(list(Type = structure(c(3L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("Community", 
"Contaminant", "Healthcare"), class = "factor"), hosp1_WoundAssocType = c(464L, 
285L, 24L), hosp1_BloodAssocType = c(73L, 40L, 26L), hosp1_UrineAssocType = c(75L, 
37L, 18L), hosp1_RespAssocType = c(137L, 77L, 2L), hosp1_CathAssocType = c(80L, 
34L, 24L), hosp2_WoundAssocType = c(171L, 115L, 17L), hosp2_BloodAssocType = c(127L, 
62L, 12L), hosp2_UrineAssocType = c(50L, 29L, 6L), hosp2_RespAssocType = c(135L, 
142L, 6L), hosp2_CathAssocType = c(95L, 24L, 12L)), .Names = c("Type", 
"hosp1_WoundAssocType", "hosp1_BloodAssocType", "hosp1_UrineAssocType", 
"hosp1_RespAssocType", "hosp1_CathAssocType", "hosp2_WoundAssocType", 
"hosp2_BloodAssocType", "hosp2_UrineAssocType", "hosp2_RespAssocType", 
"hosp2_CathAssocType"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
```

Which looks as follows

```
require(dplyr)
df <- tbl_df(SO_Example_v1)
head(df)
         Type hosp1_WoundAssocType hosp1_BloodAssocType hosp1_UrineAssocType
1  Healthcare                  464                   73                   75
2   Community                  285                   40                   37
3 Contaminant                   24                   26                   18
Variables not shown: hosp1_RespAssocType (int), hosp1_CathAssocType (int), hosp2_WoundAssocType
  (int), hosp2_BloodAssocType (int), hosp2_UrineAssocType (int), hosp2_RespAssocType (int),
  hosp2_CathAssocType (int)
```

The column `Type` is the type of bacteria, the following columns represent where they were cultured. The digits represent the number of times the respective type of bacteria were detected.

I know what my final table should look like, but until now I have been doing it step by step for each comparison and variable and there must undoubtedly be a way to do this by piping multiple functions in `dplyr` - but alas, I have not found the answer on SO to this.

Example of what final table should look like

```
                                                 Wound
Type                            n Hospital 1 (%)      n Hospital 2 (%)  p-val
Healthcare associated bacteria     464 (60.0)            171 (56.4)     0.28
Community associated bacteria      285 (36.9)            115 (38.0)     0.74
Contaminants                       24 (3.1)              17 (5.6)       0.05
```

Where the first grouping variable "Wound" is then subsequently replaced by "Urine", "Respiratory", ... and then there's a final column termed "All/Total", which is the total number of times each variable in the rows of "Type" was found and summarized across Hospital 1 and 2 and then compared.

What I have done until now is the following and very tedious, as it's calculated "by hand" and then I poulate the table with all of the results manually.

```
### Wound cultures & healthcare associated (extracted manually)
# hosp1 464 (yes), 309 (no), 773 wound isolates in total; (% = 464 / 309 * 100)
# hosp2 171 (yes), 132 (no), 303 would isolates in total; (% = 171 / 303 * 100)

### Then the chisq.test of my contingency table
chisq.test(cbind(c(464,309),c(171,132)),correct=FALSE)
```

I appreciate that if I run a piped `dplyr` on the raw data.frame I won't be able to get the exact formatting of my desired table, but there must be a way to at least automate all the steps here and put the results together in a final table that I can export as a .csv file and then just do some final column editing etc.?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: There are a lot of questions contained in this single posting.  You might want your data to be tidy; it is not, as you have two variables (hospital # and cultured location) contained in one variable.  Could make it hard to iterate through cultured locations to create the different tables.

You could convert your data to a tidy format:

    `library(tidyr)`
    `names(df) <- gsub("AssocType","",names(df))`
    `df2 <- gather(df,type,count,-Type)`
    `df3 <- separate(df2, type, into = c("hospital","location"), sep = "_")`

Then if you need it wide again, use `spread()`.

Comment: Here's an [explanation of tidy data](http://vita.had.co.nz/papers/tidy-data.pdf).

Comment: Thanks Sam. `tidyr` has been installed for a while, but I never got round to using it and reading the vignette. Knowing a little bit about how HW makes packages that deal with "real-life" problems of dataanalysts, it's no surprise, that this has a pretty decent solution for cleaning it up. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's ugly, but it works (Sam in the comments is right that this whole issue should probably be addressed by adjusting your data to a clean format before analysing, but anyway):

```
Map(
  function(x,y) {
    out <- cbind(x,y)
    final <- rbind(out[1,],colSums(out[2:3,]))
    chisq.test(final,correct=FALSE)
  },
  SO_Example_v1[grepl("^hosp1",names(SO_Example_v1))],
  SO_Example_v1[grepl("^hosp2",names(SO_Example_v1))] 
)

#$hosp1_WoundAssocType
#
#        Pearson's Chi-squared test
#
#data:  final
#X-squared = 1.16, df = 1, p-value = 0.2815
# etc etc...
```

Matches your intended result:

```
chisq.test(cbind(c(464,309),c(171,132)),correct=FALSE)
#
#        Pearson's Chi-squared test
# 
#data:  cbind(c(464, 309), c(171, 132))
#X-squared = 1.16, df = 1, p-value = 0.2815
```

Comment: Ha. That's a pretty nifty function there. And it automates a lot of the "raw" hand work I did following your input yesterday. Thank you. Question though, when I now want to take the second row (e.g. "community"), and I edit the funciton as follows
`Map(
  function(x,y) {
    out <- cbind(x,y)
    final <- rbind(out[2,],colSums(out[1,3,]))
    chisq.test(final,correct=FALSE)
  },
  SO_Example_v1[grepl("^hosp1",names(SO_Example_v1))],
  SO_Example_v1[grepl("^hosp2",names(SO_Example_v1))] 
)`; I get an `error in out[1, 3, ] : incorrect number of dimensions`...can't see the syntax error off hand..

Comment: `out[1,3,]` is trying to select the `1`st row, `3`rd column, and all strata (3rd dimension). I think you want `out[c(1,3),]`

Comment: thanks. Stupid me, totally forgot some basics right there, sorry. For the last column of my table which is the total of all rows in `Type`, I'd need to change `colSums[...]` to `rowSums[...]`, right? Thanks again. Accepted of course as answers major issue at hand.

Comment: Actually, doesn't work...tried doing it and it gets and error, saying its out of bounds. Tried manipulating the code a bit, but no chance.