# How can you loop this higher-order function in R?

Tags: r, function, loops, chi-squared

This question relates to the reply I received [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29022735/how-do-summarize-this-data-table-with-dplyr-then-run-a-chisq-test-or-similar/29023069?noredirect=1#comment46289409_29023069) with a nice little function from [thelatemail](https://stackoverflow.com/users/496803/thelatemail). 
The dataframe I'm using is not optimal, but it's what I've got and I'm simply trying to loop this function across all rows.

This is my df

```
dput(SO_Example_v1)
structure(list(Type = structure(c(3L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("Community", 
"Contaminant", "Healthcare"), class = "factor"), hosp1_WoundAssocType = c(464L, 
285L, 24L), hosp1_BloodAssocType = c(73L, 40L, 26L), hosp1_UrineAssocType = c(75L, 
37L, 18L), hosp1_RespAssocType = c(137L, 77L, 2L), hosp1_CathAssocType = c(80L, 
34L, 24L), hosp2_WoundAssocType = c(171L, 115L, 17L), hosp2_BloodAssocType = c(127L, 
62L, 12L), hosp2_UrineAssocType = c(50L, 29L, 6L), hosp2_RespAssocType = c(135L, 
142L, 6L), hosp2_CathAssocType = c(95L, 24L, 12L)), .Names = c("Type", 
"hosp1_WoundAssocType", "hosp1_BloodAssocType", "hosp1_UrineAssocType", 
"hosp1_RespAssocType", "hosp1_CathAssocType", "hosp2_WoundAssocType", 
"hosp2_BloodAssocType", "hosp2_UrineAssocType", "hosp2_RespAssocType", 
"hosp2_CathAssocType"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
####################
#what it looks like#
####################
require(dplyr)
df <- tbl_df(SO_Example_v1)
head(df)
         Type hosp1_WoundAssocType hosp1_BloodAssocType hosp1_UrineAssocType
1  Healthcare                  464                   73                   75
2   Community                  285                   40                   37
3 Contaminant                   24                   26                   18
Variables not shown: hosp1_RespAssocType (int), hosp1_CathAssocType (int), hosp2_WoundAssocType
  (int), hosp2_BloodAssocType (int), hosp2_UrineAssocType (int), hosp2_RespAssocType (int),
  hosp2_CathAssocType (int)
```

The function I have is to perform a `chisq.test` across all categories in `df$Type`. Ideally the function should switch to a `fisher.test()` if the cell count is <5, but that's a separate issue (extra brownie points for the person who comes up with how to do that though).

This is the function I'm using to go row by row

```
func <- Map(
  function(x,y) {
    out <- cbind(x,y)
    final <- rbind(out[1,],colSums(out[2:3,]))
    chisq <- chisq.test(final,correct=FALSE)
    chisq$p.value
  },
  SO_Example_v1[grepl("^hosp1",names(SO_Example_v1))],
  SO_Example_v1[grepl("^hosp2",names(SO_Example_v1))] 
)
func
```

But ideally, i'd want it to be something like this

```
for(i in 1:nrow(df)){func}
```

But that doesn't work. A further hook is, that when for example, row two is taken, the `final` call looks like this

```
func <- Map(
  function(x,y) {
    out <- cbind(x,y)
    final <- rbind(out[2,],colSums(out[c(1,3),]))
    chisq <- chisq.test(final,correct=FALSE)
    chisq$p.value
  },
  SO_Example_v1[grepl("^hosp1",names(SO_Example_v1))],
  SO_Example_v1[grepl("^hosp2",names(SO_Example_v1))] 
)
func
```

so the function should understand that the cell count its taking for `out[x,]` has to be excluded from `colSums()`. This `data.frame` only has 3 rows, so it's easy, but I've tried applying this function to a separate data.frame I have that consists >200 rows, so it would be nice to be able to loop this somehow.

Any help appreciated.

Cheers

Comment: why not perform a contingency table chi-squared across the whole dataset? it looks like you have a 3 categories by 11 categories contingency table.

Comment: Thank you. The reason is because I want the information for subgroup comparisons and running it over 3x11 contigency table will just let me know that there are differences between groups, but not which one's are different. Granted I could look at the percentages to get a feel for what's going on but, I'm specifically interested in subgroup comparisons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were missing two things:

1. To select the line *i* and select all but this line you want to use 
   `u[i]` and `u[-i]`
2. If an item is not the same length than the others given to Map, it is recycled, a very general property of the language. You then just have to add an argument to the function that corresponds to the line you want to oppose to the others, it will be recycled for all the items of the vectors passed.

The following does what you asked for

```
    # the function doing the stats
    FisherOrChisq <- function(x,y,lineComp) {
        out <- cbind(x,y)
        final <- rbind(out[lineComp,],colSums(out[-lineComp,]))
        test <- chisq.test(final,correct=FALSE)

        return(test$p.value)
    }

    # test of the stat function
    FisherOrChisq(SO_Example_v1[grep("^hosp1",names(SO_Example_v1))[1]],
    SO_Example_v1[grep("^hosp2",names(SO_Example_v1))[1]],2)

    # making the loop
    result <- c()
    for(type in SO_Example_v1$Type){
        line <- which(SO_Example_v1$Type==type)
        res <- Map(FisherOrChisq,
                    SO_Example_v1[grepl("^hosp1",names(SO_Example_v1))],
                    SO_Example_v1[grepl("^hosp2",names(SO_Example_v1))],
                    line
                )
        result <- rbind(result,res)
    }
    colnames(result) <- gsub("^hosp[0-9]+","",colnames(result))
    rownames(result) <- SO_Example_v1$Type
```

That said, what you are doing is very heavy multiple testing. I would be extremely cautious with the use of the corresponding p-values, you need at least to use a multiple testing correction such as what is suggested [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_comparisons_problem#What_can_be_done).

Comment: That's quite some nice programming there and a very nice presentation of the results. Thank you. However, if you look at the results of the first function I provided, the calculated p-values differ from your results. The correct contigency table of for example WoundAssocType is as follows: 
`[1,] 464 171 [2,] 309 132`. And running `chisq.test(cbind(c(464, 309), c(171, 132)), correct=F)`, also returns a different p-value to your calculation. Any idea why? Re: Multiple testing, I am aware of the issue, butdon't completely agree, but no space to discuss and we can chat about that in later posts.

Comment: For the Healthcare vs sum of the others, (the contingency table you give), my code uses the same contingency table and returns p-value 0.3014186 as it is of course using the fisher test, less than 5 points was your cutoff right? Here we have 2...

Comment: Hi `chisq.test(cbind(c(464, 309), c(171, 132)), correct=F)` returns a pvalue of 0.2815. The cutoff is for counts per cell in the contigency table. If one cell < 5, `then fisher.test()`. Why does your code assign a `fisher.test()` when all cells are >100? Thanks for everything.

Comment: It is corrected. If any cell in the contingency table is under 5 it uses fisher.test

Comment: I will provide you with the bounty, as it is pretty much what I asked for (thank you by the way!), but I've noticed, that the function will run a fisher.test() on all contingency tables of a row, if any one of a contigency tables has a cell-count <5. Ideally, the function should check for each contigency table created (i.e. Wound, Blood, Cath etc.) if a cell has a count < 5 and then either use a fisher.test() or chisq.test(). So it would have to alternate between a fisher and chisq across the row. RE: multiple testing. The table may look that way, but it is in fact a separate test every time.

Comment: Now the answer is *exactly* what you asked for. For the Fisher/chisq alternative you can try asking an other question but be careful there are limits to making unpaid labor force of fairly skilled people. I hardly see any effort on your side to solve your problems.

Comment: Not aiming at making anyone angry nor was I trying to make someone develop a function for me that I'm going to run off with and use etc. Overall I was intrigued by the inclusion of the if/else statement and how that may create an issue when looping across rows and columns. E.g. was simply commenting on your code. As I said, you provided the right answer for which I am very grateful and thus rightfully earnt the bounty.